# count distinct value in django model field

Tags: python, django, charts

Hi I have a django model which has two field 'date' and 'result'.

```
+----------+-------------+--------------------------
|date                                     | result |  
+----------+-------------+--------------------------
|2017-03-27                               | passed | 
|2017-03-27                               | passed | 
|2017-03-27                               | passed | 
|2017-03-27                               | failed |
|2017-03-27                               | failed | 
|2017-03-26                               | passed |
|2017-03-26                               | failed |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------------
```

I need to count the value of result following way

date 2017-03-27  passed=3 and failed=2

One of the probable solution is following

```
Results.objects.filter(date=date.today()).values('result').annotate(passed=Count('result'))},
```

I am using above command in the django chartit in order to draw pie chart to show total number of passed and failed value.

View:

```
def chart(request):
    resultdata = DataPool(
           series=
            [{'options': {
               'source': Results.objects.filter(date=date.today()).values('result').annotate(passed=Count('result'))},
              'terms':[
                'date',
                'passed']}
             ])
    cht = Chart(
            datasource = resultdata,
            series_options =
              [{'options':{
                  'type': 'pie','stacking': False,
                  },
                'terms':{
                  'date':[
                    'passed']
                  }}],
            chart_options =
              {'title': {
                   'text': 'Result of test cases'},
              })
```

But it assign the count value both to "passed" variable.I need to show in two separate variable 
passed and failed. How can I separate the value?

Comment: What is the Django version you are using

Comment: Django Version is 1.8.7

Answer (score -1):

```
Results.objects.filter(date=date.today()).values('result').annotate(passed=Count('result'), failed=Count('result'))
```

give annotate two arguement and the returned QuerySet will have two dict which include both "passed" and "failed"

Comment: Please provide your answer with clear descriptions. Don't write the code, give the explanation about the code which you have shared, so that others can also understand and it will be helpful. I request you to read the FAQ Section in-order to use Stack Overflow in an effective manner.